# How to get all Graph Nodes in ArangoDB without Start-Node

Tags: graph, orientdb, graph-databases, arangodb, aql

Like in OrientDB, for get the All Graph Only use 'Select From v'
[image]

So far, I have use AQL in ArangoDB with start node:

```
for v,e,p IN 2 ANY 'user/188802' graph 'a' return p
```

And now I want to get all graph nodes in ArangoDB without the start node?

Comment: I was trying to achieve the same. For example, list all "person -> cellphone" sub-graphs where person.firstName = "Paul" and cellphone.manufacturer = "Samsung".
I know it can be easily done in neo4j but I'm not sure how to do it in Arango.

Answer (score 2):

Graphs are a grouping of Edge collections. Each Edge collection references _from and _to documents which are stored in Document collections.

The graph traversal queries expect you to have a starting position and it returns the results for that single starting position.

It is possible to identify all possible starting positions, and then run graph traversals over those positions.

You'll need to know the names of the document collections that make up your graph, you can insert them into an AQL query like this:

```
FOR vertex IN UNION(
        (FOR v IN document_collection_1 RETURN v._id),
        (FOR v IN document_collection_2 RETURN v._id),
        (FOR v IN document_collection_3 RETURN v._id)
    )
    FOR v, e IN 1..5 OUTBOUND vertex GRAPH 'my_graph_name' OPTIONS { uniqueVertices: true }
    RETURN DISTINCT [
        { 
            _from: e._from,
            _to: e._to
        }
    ]
```

Remember that in ArangoDB it is possible for a document collection to be bound to more than one graph, so you'll need to ensure you identify all document collections that are part of the graph.

This query will then extract an array of objects that contain all links defined in the graph. This query focuses only on vertices with edges that are part of the graph. If the vertex has no edge on it, it won't appear in the output as it is not part of the graph.